# Connect remote Friend to local LANparty

Tags: networking, vpn, internet, routing, lan

I would like to make a LAN party with some friends but unfortunately someone moved a few hundred kilometers away.

Now my issue is, how could he join us and play together with us, like being in the room but playing in the LAN Multiplayer of old games, not online. So not only connecting 2 people but one local network to another person who basically joins the existing network.

How can I achieve that?

I suspect it should be possible using some kind of VPN or possibly VLAN or something. Since he isn't very advanced when it comes to computers, it would be great if the solution would be as easy as using a program.

---

Update to see if i get it right:

Switch: Connected to like Local 5 friends, -- and to my Pc, -- as well as the router(internet).

On My Pc: I install (for example) hamachi, -- start hamachi and host a VPN with it, -- wait for my Remote friend to connect to the hamachi VPN, -- Start a game and Host in LAN modus.

Remote Friend: Installs hamachi, -- connects to my hosted hamachi VPN, -- starts game and searches for LAN games.

Local friends: just plug in the switch, -- start game and search for LAN games.

--> Everybody plays together

---

Here a (very pretty) Picture to make it a little more clear.
would this work with an of the shelf hamachi? or do I need OpenVPN and configure it a little? (if so how?)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLmtb.png)

Comment: [Hamachi](https://www.vpn.net/) is a straightforward way to do it without much hassle.

Comment: I persnonally never had a good expierence with hamachi,. Would it work since not all people would use hamchi but just one?

Comment: When I last used it (couple of years ago), it worked fine. For that question i can't answer because all of my friends were on their homes.
You can still create a VPN connection to your home network, that will require some knowledge on your side.

Comment: I added a picture, can you tell me if I got it right an this will work?

Comment: @G.M Work yes; be secure, depends on what you did on the router. A WAN exposed VPN server is ideally ran on a router, or within a router OS, which has the necessary security features to firewall the WAN side traffic correctly. It's definitely not recommended to run the VPN server on the PC if it's not running in a virtualized environment _(unless you know exactly what you're doing, you'll ensure you're exploitable, as you're exposing a specific UDP port on the PC to WAN - if exposing more than one port and/or did not granularly configure the PC's firewall, your setup is most definitely wrong)_

Comment: cccccktlrfcceufdnninlkhfitlrlctddflrjbbjllhccccccktlrfcjbktgrdheidlbuerjinhebtvunbbcnrr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, a VPN would allow your friend to connect to your network and would allow you to play LAN games together.

There are a variety of methods to set up a VPN.  Some router's offer VPN capabilities built in.  Check your router's manual to see if the service is available.  However, these features only come in more advanced routers, which are not typically provided by ISPs.

VPN server software would be the other choice.  You didnt say which operating system you are using, but I am assuming Windows.  However, much of the same is offered on Linux and Mac OS X.  There are a lot of options, such as [these](https://opensource.com/article/18/8/open-source-tools-vpn).  Technically, you dont even need to install any software with this [method](https://www.howtogeek.com/135996/how-to-create-a-vpn-server-on-your-windows-computer-without-installing-any-software/).

Alternatively, Steam offers [Steam Remote Play](https://store.steampowered.com/remoteplay/#together), which allows remote player to play a growing list of LAN games remotely.

Comment: Thanks, for the great answer, would all of these solutions allow me to play with a local lan group and connect with an outside friend at the same time? It kinda sounds that everybody needs to connect via vpn, but that would certainly slow down latency.

Comment: @G.M  You have it backwards.  You want to set up the VPN on the LAN and have the remote person connect to it.  That will put him on the LAN.  The remote person will have higher latency, but you cant break the laws of physics

Comment: Ah, poor choice of words on my part, maybe I can make it more clear. Please have look at my original post I updated it a little.

Comment: @G.M The only person connecting to the VPN would be the remote player.  When he is connected, he will be on the LAN.

Comment: @Keltari You can lower latency on OpenVPN by tuning the configs versus using the cookie-cutter configs nearly everyone seems intent on using on the internet,  Examples of a tuned [server](https://github.com/JW0914/Wikis/blob/master/Scripts%2BConfigs/OpenVPN/OpenVPN-Server.conf) and [client](https://github.com/JW0914/Wikis/blob/master/Scripts%2BConfigs/OpenVPN/Client.ovpn) configs. The fastest throughput will, generally, be obtained via an SSL VPN [OpenVPN].

Comment: @JW0914 That may be.  However, the fact that the remote player is physically further away, travelling through multiple hops, and dealing with encryption, he will be slower.

Comment: @Keltari I didn't say their throughput will be optimal, I stated lower latency can be obtained by tuning the OpenVPN configs, _which is recommended anyways except majority never bother doing the research to discover this, preferring the cookie-cutter, basic configs almost everyone seems to use_.  The only way the OP can accomplish this is via a VPN, and an SSL VPN will almost always offer lower latency, _if tuned_, than an IPSec VPN (WireGuard _may_ be the IPSec exception); however, the remote player will be locked to the upload speed of the ISP plan the OP is behind.

Comment: I added a picture, can you tell me if I got it right an this will work?

Comment: @G.M yes, thats correct.